# How to get selected items from a dynamically populated Checkbox Group inside Flow Builder

Tags: visual-workflow, checkbox, flow-builder

I have a dynamically populated `Checkbox Group` element on a `Flow Builder` screen which has many checkbox items.

When a user makes multiple selections - how do I get all these selections?

It appears that the `Record Choice Set` only outputs a single selection and not the other items selected.

Essentially there can be only one output from a multiple select checkbox group?

How do I get all the selected items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Record Choice Set retains a concatenated string value (of Choice Stored Values - typically record IDs) of the selected choices.  This then needs to be parsed to get to the individual values.

A good approach is to use a separate lookup to create an sObject collection variable, which replicates the dynamic choice lookup, then parse the dynamic choice output string to check if it contains the id (i.e. it was selected).  It's a bit painful, but works.

1) Ensure that your dynamic record choice is storing the record ID

[image]

2) Take note of the record choice API name
[image]

3) Assign choice to a text variable
[image]

4) Work through your separate lookup to see if the ID is 'contained' in the returned string...
[image]

Comment: More detail added - with screenshots.  Code is much easier to share!

Comment: The API Name of Checkbox Group is actually returning concatenated values of the Record Choice Set Label (i.e. Name) but not the Value (i.e. ID). I followed the exact thing as per your screenshot. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am having the same issue as @KrishnanduSarkar